# XSLT to Get value of a single attribute among multiple attributes to same field value

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes

I have an xml

`<PiecesTransportationQuantity unitCode="EA" text="1.0"/>`

Need to convert as value of "text" attribute to the same field value and attribute unitCode should remain as an attribute:

`<PiecesTransportationQuantity unitCode="EA"> 1.0 </PiecesTransportationQuantity>`

Requesting to provide an xslt for the same .

I have used

```
<xsl:template match="PiecesTransportationQuantity/@unitCode/@text">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
```

</xsl:template>

Comment: The pattern `PiecesTransportationQuantity/@unitCode/@text` will never match anything: an attribute cannot be a child of another attribute.

Comment: Can't use pattern like ```/@unitCode/@text```. As @michael.hor257k pointed above, you can use a single attribute at a time to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your stylesheet also has the [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT_2) template, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="PiecesTransportationQuantity/@text">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Otherwise you need to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="PiecesTransportationQuantity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@unitCode"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
<xsl:template match="PiecesTransportationQuantity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="unitCode" select="@unitCode"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You are assuming OP can use XSLT 2.0 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern used in your template (*using two attributes simultaniously*) match will not match anything.

If you want to use your code pattern, then try:

```
<xsl:template match="PiecesTransportationQuantity">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@* except @text"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

else you can use the 2nd suggestion from @michael.hor257k's answer:

Comment: 1. There is no need to use `xsl:element` here; you can simply do `xsl:copy` or even a literal `<PiecesTransportationQuantity>`. -- 2. You too are assuming XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Right @michael.hor257k, just used OP's pattern using ```xsl:element```, that's why mentioned your ans. thanks...